# Python 3.10 .join function questions

Tags: python, string, list, printing

So let's say, i want to do something thing like this

```
a = ['AB', 'CD']
s = '1. \n'
print(s.join(a))
```

Expected Output:

```
1. AB
2. CD
```

Actual Output:

```
AB1.
CD1.
```

So my question is,
How can i add something at the beginning of the string `s`?
And also increase the number.

example:

```
1. ...
2. ...
```

Comment: The "Actual Output" does not show the actual output from the first code snippet.

Comment: Why are you expecting that? `join()` just puts the delimiter string in between all the list elements. Why would it put it at the beginning, or increment the number?

Comment: To do what you want, write a loop using `enumerate(a)`

Comment: `for i, s in enumerate(a, start=1): print(f'{i}. {s}')`

Comment: `list(map(lambda x: str(x[0]+1)+'.' + x[1].join(s), enumerate(a)))`

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = ['AB', 'CD']
rs = ""
for i, v in enumerate(a):
    rs += f"{i + 1}. {v}\n"
print(rs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` and a list comprehension to create that string:

```
a = ['AB', 'CD']

s = '\n'.join(
    f"{idx}. {val}"
    for idx, val in enumerate(a, 1))
```